Question regarding the traversing behaviour of preceding axes when used with / and //


<div id="moe-osm-pusher" style="display: block !important; height: 0px;">
    <div><p>A44</p></div>
    
</div>

<div id="x">
        <p>A</p>
        <div>
          <div>  <p>A11</p> </div>

            <div>
                <p>A12</p>
                <div>
                    <p>A13</p>
     
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>A23</p>
                    <div><p>A00</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>A22</p>
                
            </div>
     </div>   
    </div>



//div[p[contains(text(),'A23')]]// preceding::div 
//div[p[contains(text(),'A23')]]/preceding::div
My question is whether first xpath will locate this <div><p>A00</p></div> or not ?
I saw in http://xpather.com/ it is locating the div but why . Isn't Xpath meant to go backwards.
Both of the xpath common output is :

<div> <p>A13</p></div>

<div>  <p>A11</p> </div>

<div><p>A44</p></div>

<div id="moe-osm-pusher" style="display: block !important; height: 0px;"></div>


which is alright.

This one had me quite puzzled. The answer lies in the nodes you can't see: whitespace-only text nodes.
The expression
//div[p[contains(text(),'A23')]]

selects the div element that is the parent of <p>A23</p>,
Now //preceding::div means /descendant-or-self::node()/preceding::div. The descendant-or-self selects a number of nodes, one of which is the whitespace text node that immediately follows the <div><p>A00</p></div> element. And when you follow the preceding axis from this whitespace text node, the result includes the <div><p>A00</p></div> element.
(As a general rule, // should only be used with the child or attribute axes. In other cases, the result can often be surprising.)

I was unable to understand what did you say . I tried to explain myself by drawing analogy with //following::  which would first traverse and locate the immediate child and then the immediate child's descendants of the current node sequentially from top to bottom and then only go to it's sibling.
Same thing happens with / preceding <-> /following . it does not traverse to its immediate child & descedent of current node

Well, I'm not sure what part you didn't understand, but you can't work this sort of thing out by drawing analogies. You need a very clear reading of the data model and the specification of axis paths.
